# childwindow.document.location.reload() not working

Tags: javascript

I cannot get the following code to work as expected:

```
function OpenResListWindow() {
  var List;
  List = window.open('MCalInsertResDraftList.asp', 'formpopup', 'width=300,height=800,location=0,menubar=0, titlebar=0,resizeable=no,scrollbars=no,top=0');
  List.location.reload() List.onblur.close();
}
```

The `formpopup` opens up and gets focus, but the `reload` and `onblur.close` never take place, and I have been running in circles to solve the mystery.

The `formpopup` contains classic ASP that opens a recordset, and the records are supposed to refresh for every new `window.open` - but the latest records are not listed before you press F5 and refresh the window manually. Is it possible to make that refresh automatic as the window opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using callback function. Invoke `List.location.reload();`  and `List.onblur.close();`after `window.open()` function call is completed.

My guess is since Javascript is asynchronous, it doesn't wait till the popup is opened completely. It should've executed the reload() and close() immediately.

Edit: Adding windows onload, will wait until the window loads completely.

```
function OpenResListWindow() {
  var List;
  List = window.open('MCalInsertResDraftList.asp', 'formpopup', 'width=300,height=800,location=0,menubar=0, titlebar=0,resizeable=no,scrollbars=no,top=0');
  List.onload = function() {  List.location.reload(); List.onblur.close();}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being with me Siva:)

okay - i tried to write this:
callback(List.location.reload());
callback(List.onblur.close);

but the formpopup still do not reload untill I press F5 - and still do not close on blur.

Do I miss something in the callback?

Comment: Hi again,
Siva, you put me on the right track - i now use timeout to delay the popup, wich gives the server time to register the new record before the popup loads it on opening:

function newres(){
 setTimeout(listfct,500);
}
 
function listfct(){
//(lots of other stuff) 
var list
 List = window.open('MCalInsertResDraftList.asp', 'formpopup', 'width=300,height=800,location=0,menubar=0, location=0, titlebar=0,resizeable=no,scrollbars=no,top=0');
 List.focus();
}